# What's the difference between HAVING and WHERE in MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, having-clause

I have a view (`viewX`) based on joins of some tables:

When I use `WHERE`, the query is delayed, processor usage goes to 50% and finally I need to close `mysqld.exe` service and restart to try to solve the problem again.

When I use `HAVING`, the query executes perfectly and quickly, I get the results and all is ready.

The query is similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM viewX WHERE column_of_view = 'foo'

SELECT * FROM viewX HAVING column_of_view = 'foo'
```

What is happening?

The solution I found is to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM viewX) as T WHERE column_of_view = 'foo'

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM viewX) as T HAVING column_of_view = 'foo'
```

BOTH QUERIES WORKS FINE, BUT, I think this is BAD! (SELECT * FROM (...viewX)????)

Comment: can you post some execution plans?

Comment: My best guess is that by using HAVING you are confusing the query optimizer just like you are confusing me, and that this confusion results in a different execution plan (different join order and methods), which in this case may actually be beneficial (with many joins, the potential for a suboptimal join order is huge). Does it just return the first few rows faster, or is the whole select for all rows also faster?

Comment: What happens if you specify both?

Comment: Does the view have an aggregate already?

Answer (score 5):

`WHERE` is for filtering query results based on condition.

`HAVING` is for applying a filter on results of an aggregate function. In absence of aggregate function it functions same as WHERE.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/

Comment: That is correct, but does not explain what is happening. In fact, it argues that there should be no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Having is used for aggregate functions like sum,avg so on and it can be using only in select statement.where clause won't work in aggregate conditions
eg: where sum(mark) > 300 // its not true

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the definition of the view - having clause should only apply to an aggregate query and its applied after the grouping.  Have you looked at the two query plans (with explain)?

Answer (score 0):

**WHERE** is used while listing and no ALIAS names are available yet

**HAVING** filters rows after listing all possible rows so ALIAS names are generated

There should be a problem while filtering rows inline.